# Showing thumbnail of Flash image using C#

Tags: c#, flash

I have a grid in my application where I show thumbnail (100*100) of images. I am using [imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net/) plugin to generate thumbnails on the fly. My image URLS are coming from third party application. Sometimes instead of images I am getting a flash file (.SWF). The plugin is throwing `ImageCorruptedException`.

As of now, I am handling the exception in `Application_Error` of Global.asax and returning back a default image URL.

Now I want to show the thumbnail of flash image instead of default image. How can I achieve this in C#? I have searched a lot on Google but no convincing answers.

Comment: A .swf file is a series of images. Which image do you want?

Comment: I want to show the entire SWF as a 100 * 100 thumbnail in my grid.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. A swf is made of frames, each being it's own image, for example a swf could be 5 images, each image showing a letter of the alphabet. When the swf is 'played' it loops through each image showing them 1 by 1. If you're making an image of that swf how do you decide which image to use.